# How to add sencha gxt palletes to eclipse juno?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, extjs, gxt

I have installed Eclipse juno EE and added google web toolkit plugins with all respective gtks. It works for me. Now I am going to add extgwt to eclipse. I downloaded last version of sencha gxt. I accomplished all steps from this instruction http://www.sencha.com/blog/setting-up-your-first-ext-gwt-project-in-eclipse/
However when I open my module in design mode I don't see the appropriate sencha gxt palletes with corresponding controls.
Where am I wrong?  What should I do to get sencha gxt control palletes in the design view in my project?

Comment: hi! any updates about this? I have the same problem.

Comment: no, it's impossible so far.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select your GWT module file and right-click to select the Google Web Toolkit > Configure for using Ext GWT (GXT) command. This will add the gxt.jar to your classpath and module file and various GXT files to your war folder.

Once Ext GWT (GXT) has been added to your project several new Ext GWT (GXT) palette categories will appear:

Keep in mind though, that is for version 2.x.  I am not sure the latest GXT 3.x works with designer anymore.

see https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/features/gwt/gxt